# How to use jQuery to reload Partial with new parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, partial-views

I have a partial view that I load in a page passing in a parameter. When the page loads, I setup two parameters `helpMember` and `helpAnonymous`.

```
{
  var helpMember = Model.Content.Children.Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("contextualHelp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ElementAt(0);
  var helpAnonymous = Model.Content.Children.Where(c => c.DocumentTypeAlias.Equals("contextualHelp", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ElementAt(1);
}
```

```html
<div id="contextual-help-partial" >
    @Html.Partial("ContextualHelp", helpMember)
</div>
```

With jQuery, how can I reload the Partial and pass `helpAnonymous` to it?

Comment: You would need to return the Partial from an AJAX request which updates the existing HTML, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3651171/asp-net-mvc-rendering-partial-view-with-jquery-ajax

Answer (score 1):

You have to create one method in controller and call that action using this. Suppose created action as `loadhtml`. return partialview from that action.

Controller action as

```
public ActionResult loadhtml(string helpMember){
   ViewBag.helpMember = helpMember;
   return PartialView("ContextualHelp");
}
```

jquery code as

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: "/loadhtml?helpMember=@helpMember",
        datatype:"html",
        success: function (data) {
           $("#contextual-help-partial").empty().html(data);
        },
        error: function (err) {
        }
    });
```

Comment: Probably a variety of ways to accomplish this but this pattern worked for me, thanks!